# width: '100%' Symbol not working in Email Body - Postman

Tags: html, css, node.js, postman, email-client

I'm trying to send an email with APIS through NodeJS, Here is what I have designed an Email with HTML and CSS.

When ever I use `%` symbol in CSS, and trigger an Email, the postman is returning error 500. But if I remove `%` symbol from every where in the code, it's working fine.

Some part of the body looks like this below snippet

```
{
"toAddress" : "author.details@example.com",
"subject"   : "Test - Mail Server",
"body"      : '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center">
                    <img align="center" border="0" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: inline-block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;width: 100%;max-width: 580px;" width="580"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>',
"fromAddress" : "example@example.com"
}
```

Entire code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/f2vr40bu/

Postman errors: [image: Status 500 from Postman]

So I'm wondering how to use '%' in the body or do we need to escape/parse some how, Any tips or suggestions would be greatly helpful. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: please add postman sceenshots

Comment: @PDHide, Added screenshots of Postman :)

Answer (score 0):

in json , only double quotes are allowed

so blow json is invalid:

```
{
"toAddress" : "author.details@example.com",
"subject"   : "Test - Mail Server",
"body"      : '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center">
                    <img align="center" border="0" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: inline-block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;width: 100%;max-width: 580px;" width="580"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>',
"fromAddress" : "example@example.com"
}
```

you have to escape double quotes and replace next line with \n. a better way to do is

```
 {
"toAddress" : "author.details@example.com",
"subject"   : "Test - Mail Server",
"body"      : "{{body}}",
"fromAddress" : "example@example.com"
}
```

and in pre-request use

```
let body = `<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;" align="center">
                        <img align="center" border="0" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image" title="Image" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: inline-block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;width: 100%;max-width: 580px;" width="580"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>`
    pm.environment.set("body",JSON.stringify(body))
```

Comment: I have tried in the following way as well https://pastebin.com/MW6MrWuq and the post man is returning the same error. or Am I missing something over here?

Comment: I mean the server returning the error, Not the postman. But if I remove % symbol it works.